# Integrate Django admin login as REST framework login

Tags: python, django

I want to use the admin page as 2 section

1. Admin site
2. Rest Framework API

After login into the admin only I have to access the REST API too.

Project Url is,

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^admin/', include('snippets.urls')),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')) )
```

My App Url is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.snippet_list),]
```

Comment: you can add a middleware for this purpose

Comment: Is there any example for this?

Comment: @itzmeontv please look the changes in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.In app `urls.py` by wrapping `login_required` decorator

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/$', login_required(views.snippet_list)),]
```

you need use real functions instead of their names.(its ok now)

**OR**

Use `middleware`, to check whether user is `authenticated`.

Comment: No , Still having the same I have change my url structure. see my question. If I go 127.0.0.1:8000/admin then I can view the /snippets but If I go directly /snippets it ask some other login window insted of admin login

Comment: your urls.py looks weird now . `/admin` for both cases.What is the indention for that ?

Comment: Actually I want the url of rest api as /admin/snippets as the same it have to use admin authentication

Comment: Then put `LOGIN_URL = `/admin/login/url/' in settings.py. I think something like, `/admin/accounts/login/`. check it